# Deploying WCF Service with ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I am having some difficulty in deploying my WCF service alongside my ASP.NET web application. I have everything working on my local machine (defined my address, bindings, contract) and I can call the service from my ASP.NET (MVC) web application. (Base URL right now is http://localhost:####/Design_Time_Address/Fully/Qualified/Service/)

Unfortunately, once I attempt to deploy, things tend to blow up.

Here is what I currently am doing. Please let me know if one or more steps are incorrect.

1. I have a service reference to my WCF Service in my ASP.NET MVC project.
2. I first attempted to just deploy the MVC project using web deploy. The MVC part worked fine, but it couldn't find my service. (Although, interestingly enough, I can see the DLLs to my service on my host.)
3. So, after messing with this for a bit, I then tried to upload my service separately via SFTP. I was able to hit the .svc file at one point, but lately I've been receiving errors. (I'm assuming this is because I've been trying to figure it out and have screwed it up royally.)
4. I get a bit confused here because I don't understand what the address should be, or how I should configure it within the WCF App.config file so that my MVC application can access it.

Like I said, I was good until I had to deploy and, unfortunately, I am unable to find any tutorials that can help me out.

What am I not understanding is what setup I need to do to be able to access my service via my MVC application through the host server? Do I need to provide the service reference in my MVC project as I'm doing now? Do I have to configure something in the WCF service directly? Is it possible just to do web deploy and Stuff Just Works(TM)?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: All you should need is the end points matching in your two web.configs. Best guess is the WCF app is not able to use the same endpoint on your deployed server as you are in dev either due to the port already being in use by IIS or due to different behaviours such as SSL transport.

Comment: @sipwiz - When you say two web.configs...I only have an app.config in my WCF Service. Do I need to change this to be a web.config?

Comment: What sort of app are you using for the WCF service? If it's self hosted in a Windows service or something then an app.config is correct. If it's being hosted by IIS then it should be a web.config.

Comment: @sipwiz - It is being hosted by IIS when I deploy it to my hosting service. So, if that's the case, I'm assuming I can copy the app.config over to the web.config? (Going to try this now.)

Comment: That could well be the issue. If you're hosting in IIS and don't have a web.config your WCF service will never be instantiated (unless you do it programmatically in global.asax.cs or similar).

Comment: @sipwiz - Okay...so...if I read this right, I should change my web.config to point to...the svc file? (I feel like I should be able to use web deploy and everything should just deploy together, but that doesn't seem to be the case.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7222/discussion-between-sipwiz-and-jascav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out the problem was very easily solved...unfortunately, in this case, I was a complete noob. Instead of creating a WCF Service Application, I had created a WCF Service Library. Switched to a WCF Service Application, set up my end points, added the DEPLOYED service to my MVC application, and it worked like a charm.

Feeling like a newbie today...

Answer (score 1):

You could go by small steps.

1. Create a new Visual Studio Solution.
2. Add a new ASP.NET Empty Web Application project to it.
3. Add a new WCF Service item to this application.
4. Publish your application to the server.
5. Ensure that the service has been successfully published to IIS by navigating to it (`http://host/myservice/service1.svc`).
6. Add a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application to your solution. This will generate a strongly typed client proxy classes allowing you to consume the service and modify your web.config in order to add a `<system.serviceModel>` section containing a client endpoint whose address is pointing to the WCF service you have published
7. Implement some code in your ASP.NET MVC 3 application that will call the service method
8. Run the ASP.NET MVC 3 application locally and it should be able to call thepublished service.
9. Publish your ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Now that you have setup everything you are ready to start implementing functionality into the service. You could either then test the service locally by changing the client endpoint in the web.config file of your ASP.NET MVC 3 application or leaving it and publishing the service.

Personally I don't use the `Add Service Reference` dialog in Visual Studio. I hate it when it touches to my web.config. I just hate when something touches to my code without my permission or verification. I use the command line [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to generate a strongly typed client for my WCF services. So I type the `svcutil.exe http://localhost:1234/service1.svc` command which generates 2 files: a .cs file containing the client proxy and an app.config file containing the service endpoint configuration (which I usually throw away as I prefer to modify the web.config of my application manually). Then I copy the .cs file to my client application.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried step-by-step, but things still blow up on deployment. I'm going to mark your answer as correct, if only because it gives other people a starting point. However, I was never able to even get the simple cases to work (other than when I ran everything locally). As soon as I deployed, things went crazy. Thanks again.